# Why we retrieve the validated input data when using form request?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I'm using Laravel 8, and in the Laravel document, I see this line of code for retrieving the validated input data then using [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation).

```
// Retrieve the validated input data...
$validated = $request->validated();
```

But if I clear this line, everything is fine! So, What is the reason for this retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->validated()` method returns information from your request that actually underwent validation. Let's use a quick scenario:

```php
dd($request->input());
// ['name' => 'John', 'middle_name' => 'Smith', 'last_name' => 'Doe']
```

If you have the following rules:

```php
$rules = ['name' => 'required', 'last_name' => 'required'];
```

Then, after running validation, calling `->validated()` will return the following:

```
dd($request->validated());
// ['first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe']
```

Notice how `middle_name` is missing? It was not included in the validation rules, and as such is stripped out.

You can read the full documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#working-with-validated-input

Note: If you're validating everything in your `$request`, i.e. `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name`, then you can use `$request->validated()`, `$request->input()` or `$request->all()`; they will all be the same.